# Crystal Reports keeps prompting for Parameter

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am having a terrible problem with crystal report 2010 for .net 4.0 (I am using the fixed 13.0.1 version but 13.0.4 is released). No matter which way I try, I am always getting a prompting dialogue box to input my one parameter value the first time.

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CustomerReport1;    
CustomerReport1.Database.Tables[0].SetDatasource ( this.dataset);        
CustomerReport1.SetParameterValue("PathLocation", Location.Text);

CustomerReport1.Parameter_PathLocation.CurrentValues.Add(Location.Text) // to be safe using CS 2010 for .net 4
CrystalReportViewer1.ReuseReportParametersOnRefresh = true; // to prevent from showing again and again.
```

I also tried this:

```
CustomerReport1.Database.Tables[0].SetDatasource ( this.dataset);        
CustomerReport1.SetParameterValue("PathLocation", Location.Text);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CustomerReport1;
```

And this:

```
CustomerReport1.Database.Tables[0].SetDatasource ( this.dataset);        
CustomerReport1.Parameter_PathLocation.CurrentValues.Add(Location.Text)

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CustomerReport1; // the parameter in the report has Optional Parameter = false, Static , Multiple Value = false .
```

Can anyone please help? I am getting frustrated with this. It worked in previous versions, but now I am getting this prompt box.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally found the solution. It doesn't prompt if we set the `DataSource` after the `ParameterValue`.

So anyone of those will work if we put them in this order:

```
// First, call SetParameterValue. Then, call SetDatasource.     
CustomerReport1.SetParameterValue("PathLocation", Location.Text);
CustomerReport1.Database.Tables[0].SetDatasource(this.dataset);

CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = CustomerReport1;
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

create the parameter but do not assign it a formula using selection formula -> record. Apply this parameter from vb or c#.net IDE by creating a text box,a label and a button. Put the selection formula on click button procedure.