# How to pass values from textbox to crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have this problem where crystal report is prompting me to enter a value even though I already pass the value from textbox in the vb form.

This is how I create the parameter:

[image: Adding parameter in crystal report]

As you can see, I named the parameter `NAME`.

And here is my code for passing the value from `TextBox` to parameter `NAME` in crystal report:

```
Private Sub indi_print_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles indi_print.Click
    Dim locatorReport As New report_viewer

    Dim rptDoc As CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    rptDoc = New indi_locatorReport 'indi_locatorReport is the Crystal Report
    rptDoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperLegal
    rptDoc.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(New CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(200, 200, 100, 1500))

    rptDoc.SetParameterValue("NAME", name_txtbox.Text)

    locatorReport.crptViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc
    locatorReport.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

When i click the `Print Button` this is the result:

[image: Crystal Report Output]

As you can see Crystal Report prompt me to enter a name. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved the problem. The problem is whenever the form `report_viewer` loads, it refreshes the crystal report. It has the `Me.crptViewer.RefreshReport()` code. I did not notice this because the crystal report viewer created this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Dim rptDoc As New indi_locatorReport
rptDoc.PrintOptions.PaperSize = CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperSize.PaperLegal
rptDoc.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(New CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(200, 200, 100, 1500))

rptDoc.SetParameterValue("NAME", name_txtbox.Text)

locatorReport.crptViewer.ReportSource = rptDoc
locatorReport.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: the result is still the same. Crystal Report is still prompting to input the name

Comment: Maybe this can solve your problem [Crystal Reports keeps prompting for Parameter] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12034859/crystal-reports-keeps-prompting-for-parameter)